# python django OR condition

Tags: python, django

I have this code:

```
{{ object.subtotal }}
```

I want to print 0 in case if `object.subtotal` is empty or false:

I've tried like this:

```
{{ object.subtotal or 0 }}
```

but I've got a server error 500

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#default) filter:

```
{{ object.subtotal|default:0 }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can, as far as I know, not use such operators as a Django template "variable". But what you can do to replace the `None`, is use the [**`default_if_none`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none) template filter:

```
{{ object.subtotal|default_if_none:0 }}
```

This will thus only get "triggered" in case the `subtotal` is `None` (not another expression with *truthiness* `False`, this thus is semantically a bit different than the Python `or`, that evaluates to the second expression in case the *first* expression has truthiness `False`).

Furthermore this is probably better implemented at the model level, and not at the template level. Templates are used to determine *how* something should be rendered, not *what* should be rendered (semantics).